# MySQL - Need to Select only rows where for an id, there are two possible numbers in another column

Tags: mysql

This is kind of a complicated question but ...

My data is set up to be

```
id         col1

1            15

1            30

2            15

2            15
```

I need to select only rows where for ONE id, col1 has both 15 and 30 as values in the table. So in this case, I would need the query to return 1 because id = 2 only has 15 in col1.

Comment: how about this? select id from (select distinct id, col1 from t) as a group by id having count(id) = 2;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must ensure both values: 15 and 30 exists on col1.

First query use EXISTS to ensure both conditions are true, [EXISTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) returns a boolean value of true if subquery returns rows, otherwise return false. The second subquery uses INNER JOIN tow times with itself. Only returns rows with same ID that has a col1 = 15 and a col1 = 30.

The result is the same.

```
SELECT  id
FROM    foo1 f1
WHERE   EXIST (SELECT 1 FROM foo1 WHERE id = f1.id AND col1 = 15)
AND     EXISTS (select 1 from foo1 where id = f1.id and  col1 = 30);


SELECT     id
FROM       foo1 f1
INNER JOIN foo1 f2 ON f2.id = f1.id AND col1 = 15
INNER JOIN foo1 f3 ON f3.id = f1.id AND col1 = 30;
```

I've set a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=000119e42b2ff45ea2386a59b89f2918) sample just to check it.

Comment: This ALMOST worked - I ended up using a sub-select statement with the inner joins.

WHERE id in (select distinct id
from foo1 f1
inner join foo1 f2 on (f1.id = f2.id and f2.col1 = 15)
inner join foo1 f3 on (f1.id = f3.id and f3.col1 = 30)

Two comments on your response (these are nit picky, but just for new people):
exist -> exists
the join on should have ( ) around it when there is an 'and'

Thank you very much for your response though ! It helped me out a lot :)